# Use ElementTree's findall() to match text of elements

Tags: python, elementtree

I'm trying to use ElementTree's findall() function to get a list of all `<planet>` elements with a name subelement `<name>Kepler</name>`. For example, I want only the first two planets returned in the following xml file:

```
<planet>
    <name>Kepler</name>
</planet>
<planet>
    <name>Kepler</name>
</planet>
<planet>
    <name>Newton</name>
</planet>
```

What's an elegant way to do this (other than finding all `<planet>` elements and looping over them)? I was hoping for something like

```
root.findall(".//planet/name[text()=='Kepler']")
```

Any hints?

Comment: Are you using `xml.etree` or `lxml.etree`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close!  In xpath the following is valid (tested in `lxml` to make sure!)

```
root.xpath('//planet[name[text()="Kepler"]]')
```

which is equivalently written:

```
root.xpath('//planet[name="Kepler"]')
```

Now, `xml.etree` doesn't seem to like the former `XPath` expression (`Invalid Predicate`?!) but it's cool with the latter.  Oh well.  So then we have:

```
root.findall('.//planet[name="Kepler"]')
```

Comment: I tend to use `lxml.etree` so there may be some `XPath` support differences between that and native `xml.etree`.  I'll actually test my code (haha) and adjust.

Comment: Ha! I prefer `lxml.etree` as well. I guess I had just assumed that the OP was using `xml.etree`.

Comment: Yup, `xml.etree` barfs at the first xpath expression.  Oops.  I should probably investigate why that is, but it's late - maybe tomorrow ;-)

Comment: ElementTree only supports a subset of XPath 1.0. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax.